# Sending text message using AT+command on node.js and serial.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am trying to send SMS AT+commands using node.js and serial.js with below command but it looks like its skipping the senders number, is this a device problem or something is missing with my code? i am using HUAWEI gsm modem attached on my COM2 and my machine is windows 7.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('COM2', {
  baudrate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: 'none'
});

console.log('port is now open');

port.on("open", function () {

    console.log('Serial communication open');
    port.write("AT");
    port.write('\r');
    port.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Received data: " + data);
    });



    gsm_message_sending(port, "test2", "89410238(example only)"); 
});

function gsm_message_sending(serial, phone_no, message) {
   serial.write("AT+CMGF=1");
    serial.write('\r');
    serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"" + phone_no + "\"");
    serial.write('\r');
    serial.write(message); 
    serial.write(Buffer([0x1A]));
    serial.write('^z');
}
```

I tried to change the line using below code but still the same output.

```
serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"");
    serial.write(phone_no);
    serial.write('"')
```

My console returns below

[image]

Any advice would be great! thanks in advance!

Comment: Any solution you got ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried your example but, looking at the code, you are calling:

```
gsm_message_sending(port, "test2", "89410238(example only)");
```

i.e. the parameters are in the wrong order, it should be:

```
gsm_message_sending(serial, phone_no, message)
```